# Null Pointer Exception while trying to print Parent - Child Parent relationship using Eclipselink JPA + Spring 3

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-mvc, eclipselink

I have the following bidirectional relationship : A Course can have several assignments.

I am getting a Null Pointer exception when I try the following:

I have the following methods in CourseController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="view/{id}/assignment/create")
public ModelAndView createAssignment(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("course/assignment/create");
    Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
    assignment.setCourse(this.courseManager.getCourse(id));
    //System.out.println(assignment.getCourse().getName()); This prints the course name correctly
    modelAndView.addObject("assignment", assignment);
    return modelAndView;
}

This is the jsp:
<form:form action="/cbass/assignment/check" method="POST" commandName="assignment">

<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
Course Name: ${assignment.course.name}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name : </td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ANd this is where the request goes from the JSP.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "check", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(
    @ModelAttribute("assignment") Assignment assignment,
    BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    assignmentValidator.validate(assignment, result);
    System.out.println(assignment.getCourse().getName());
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        //if validator failed
        return "course/assignment/create";
    } else {
        status.setComplete();
        //form success
        System.out.println("Hello"+assignment.getCourse().getName());
        this.assignmentManager.create(assignment);
        return "course/assignment/view";//+assignment.getId();
    }
}
```

Although I am able to see the course name properly in the JSP page,

```
Course Name: ${assignment.course.name}
```

I still get a Null Pointer Exception when I try to execute this:

```
assignment.getCourse().getName()
```

I am new to Spring and EclipseLink JPA. Please help.

Comment: Did you check the course is coming back in the post. I understand that you are priting Course name in the jsp, that is during the response but when submitting were you able to see the course inside the assignment in server debug mode. my guess is since you don't have a mapping ( i mean path binding for the course object) its coming back as null and hence you are getting a null pointer exception. check this in debug mode, keep a break point in the line you are getting exception and check the instance of assignment whether it has the course object or not.

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me how to do the mapping as mentioned:

"my guess is since you don't have a mapping ( i mean path binding for the course object)"

Comment: I did what you had mentioned. The course object is having a null value

Comment: you have done this in your jsp right <form:input path="name" />, this is the mapping or binding. So you must be having a name attribute in your assignment object right. Like that you should map the course name as well, something like <form:input path="course.name" />, then automatically spring creates a course object and set the name and also set the course inside the assignment object. since this mapping is not there in the jsp the course object is null.

Comment: I tried the same <form:hidden path="course.name" />, This creates the course object with the name but rest all attributes of the course object are null.

Comment: Yes you have to map the set of attributes which you want to have a mapping in the front end. If you are not mapping there are chances that you may lose the data. If you feel my earlier comments helped in a way to understand and fix the issue please accept and vote for the answer. If you need more information please take a look at the spring reference manual http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

Comment: Hi raddykrish, it didn't help me resolve my issue.

I want to create a child (assignment). For that I want to set the course (Parent).

Comment: i hope the problem that you have asked in the question (null pointer) got resolved. The point you are asking in the last comment is something like a design query. The way you have put in this question is like one assignment can have one course associated to it but one course can have multiple assignments. am i right? I don't understand your point " I want to create a child (assignment). For that I want to set the course (Parent)". Create it if you have such a design and build the objects with one to many and many to one relationship and set in UI and bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your course is null.  Ensure you are maintaining both sides of the relationship.

Comment: No, my course is not null, because I can see the course name in the JSP page